# How to style second level list of ExpandableListView?

Tags: android

How to change style of second level list of `ExpandableListView`? For example, add background color or header\footer view.

Note, that I don't need to set background to **each** child. I need to set style for a **whole** second level.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve (brown layout - is second level list):

[image]

As I said, I don't need to apply style for each item individually. Because I have a repeatable image at background (not just color). I know how apply styles and how to set it to each child view, but this is not what I can use to achieve such background.

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. add shadow at the top of "At the cafe". It can be done easily with `ListView`, but how to get `ListView` in such case? Is there any `ListView` at all?
2. set repeatable image as a background of **second level list** (not for each child view individually).

Comment: `android:style="@style/mysubStyle"`?

Comment: @userSeven7s Where should I apply this style? If I apply this to ExpandableListView itself, then, I assume, the whole style will be changed (including first and second levels). I need to style only second level.

Comment: You have to apply to each item in sub level.. while adding in getview method..

Comment: @userSeven7s as I said, I don't need to style each item of list individually. Because I want to apply a background with pattern image to whole second level. If I do, as you said, there will be problems with that.

Comment: See if  `getGroupView` method of ExpandableListAdpater helps..

Comment: @userSeven7s `getGroupView` returns view from first level list. However, thanks )

Comment: I am not seeing a "brown layout", can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be achieved is with the following.

Create a [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) `xml` in your `res/values/` directory.

Now define your [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) however you want it. When used this way it will change all the `Views` where the [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) is applied to this particular [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Here is my example i tested with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="backgroundTest" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">

        <item name="android:background">#00FF00</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

Now add the [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to your top level layout in the xml that defines the children for your `ExpandableListView`. For example, here is my child (note the `style` in my `LinearLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/backgroundTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightSideTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This should change the color of all your children to green, i believe. You can change the [`style`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to whatever you want. There is some great documentation that i linked that should help you out.

Comment: As I said, I don't need to apply style for each item individually. Because I have a repeatable image at background (not just color). I know how apply styles and how to set it to each child view, but this is not what I can use to achieve such background.

Comment: Well it is difficult to understand your exact goal from your question. See if you can clarify it a little better. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no secondary level ListView in the stock ExpandableListView implementation. All the items are on the same level of the view hierarchy (children of the ExpandableListView itself). In other words, the views returned from getGroupView() and getChildView() ends up as siblings instead of parent/child or aunt/niece relationship :)